# How to restrict any specific characters in textbox to be entered. I want to restrict only ^ and %

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I tried below way but it restrict all the special character. Not sure how I can  restrict only specific characters.

```
 $(function(){

$('#test').keypress(function (e) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});


});

<input type="text" id="test"/>
```

Comment: Are you saying you do, or do not, want to allow `^` and `%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape your chars

```
var regex = new RegExp("[^\\^\\%]");
```

Fiddle ==> http://jsfiddle.net/6j8sa9qz/10/

Just remove the first `^` if you want to only allow the chars

Also, since the regex is not dynamic, you could declare it outside of the keypress function. Otherwise it's declared again and again each time the user presses a key!
And actually you don't need to return `true`, so you could simplify

```
$(function(){
    var regex = new RegExp("[^\\^\\%]");
    $('#test').keypress(function (e) {

        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (!regex.test(str)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply test if the char does not match the regex for `either % or ^`:

The regex is:

```
/%|\^/
```

and this is your code:

```js
$(function() {

  $('#test').keypress(function(e) {
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    return !(/%|\^/.test(str))
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

Comment: Technically this could be reduced to `return !(/%|\^/.test(str))` as returning false effectively does preventDefault and more.

Comment: Actually the group `[%\^]` is faster than `%|\^`

Comment: Worked. Thanks @Luca

Comment: @Sampgun I found them being in 2-4% of each other

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

The below will allos all Case Letters , Numbers & Special characters except ^ and %

```
[a-zA-Z_0-9@\!#\$\&*()+=\-[]\\\';,\.\/\{\}\|\":<>\? ]
```